# iOS - Interface layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, interface

I need to achieve the following interface layout:

[image]

The obvious path would be a table view, but how would I do the top player and the bottom button set doing that? Embedding buttons in a table view row is a little unsightly I'd say, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a composed hierarchy of `UIView`s to me.  The topmost element is a custom `UIView` subclass whose subviews, in turn, are comprised of the appropriate controls.  Next down, is a `UIButton`, then your `UITableView` (does it scroll?  It looks like perhaps not.)  Then another row of buttons (trash, etc.)

So, to summarize, your base view is just a `UIView` that you compose with subviews, including what I assume is a grouped `UITableView` in the middle.  It will be easiest to layout in IB.

Comment: The table view does not scroll it's only to display some values, now how can I achieve this hierarchy? My controller would be a simple view controller? The part that would confuse me the most here is the table view inside of the view.

Comment: Yes, the base view would be your `UIViewController`'s view.  Although you most often work with `UITableViewController` to manage table views, it's not necessary, so long as your view controller conforms to the the `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` protocols and you have an IBOutlet for your table view.  You will just need to provide the data source and delegate methods.  (The view controller template will not provide them for you.)  Again, laying out in IB will help.

Comment: I'm doing so as we speak, I just wasn't aware of what you just stated, than you Alan.

Comment: I get an error saying that static table views are only valid when embedding in a UITableViewController

Comment: Yeah, I added a comment to the other answer saying that already.  You can't use a **static** tableview like this, but you can a dynamic one.

Comment: But this isn't dynamic content that I'm showing just a set of values

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple table views within a UIView. Or you can put the top and bottom controls in the table header and footer. A quick example:

[image: Quick Example]

Comment: Note that a **static** table view MUST be embedded in a UITableViewController. (it will not work in a UIViewController)